# Weil bound for characters sums

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, textbook-recommendation, algebraic-curves, characters

Do you know any good reference on Weil bounds for character sums over algebraic curves?
I prefer references which assume little previous knowledge.

Comment: Possibly useful: http://www.math.ethz.ch/~kowalski/ik-ant-exp-sums.pdf

Comment: I did some retagging, mainly because this was already on the front page. The two answers so far are both lecture notes or textbooks, and I suspect you're going to get mostly textbook type answers because you want it to assume little background.

Comment: The link in a [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/75301/weil-bound-for-characters-sums-reference-request/75304#comment191799_75301) above points to a PDF of Chapter 11 "Sums over finite fields" from this book: _Iwaniec, Henryk; Kowalski, Emmanuel_, Analytic number theory, Colloquium Publications. American Mathematical Society 53. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS) (ISBN 0-8218-3633-1/hbk). xi, 615 p. (2004). [Zbl 1059.11001](https://zbmath.org/1059.11001).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, check out Chapter 8 of this paper:

*Chen, Xi; Kayal, Neeraj; Wigderson, Avi*, [**Partial derivatives in arithmetic complexity and beyond**](https://doi.org/10.1561/0400000043), Found. Trends Theor. Comput. Sci. 6, No. 1–2, 1–138 (2010). [Zbl 1278.68010](https://zbmath.org/1278.68010). [PDF](https://www.math.ias.edu/%7Eavi/PUBLICATIONS/MYPAPERS/CKW11/CKW11.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

D. R. Kohel and I. E. Shparlinski, '[On exponential sums and group generators for elliptic curves over finite fields](https://doi.org/10.1007/10722028_24)', Lect. Notes in Comp. Sci., Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 1838 (2000),  395–404. [Zbl 1032.11034](https://zbmath.org/1032.11034)